# Connecting to Universal Robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to connect to my UR3e via ROS 2. For this i installed [ROS 2 Foxy](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html). To connect to my UR, I installed the [Universal Robot package](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/tree/foxy)

Now i have some issues, when i finally want to connect to the Robot.
I installed the "externalcontrol-1.0.5.urcap" file on the teach pendant. The Pendant is running with the polyscope version 5.12.4. When i start

```
ros2 launch ur_bringup ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur3e robot_ip:=192.168.1.102 use_fake_hardware:=true launch_rviz:=true
```

i get following error:

```
[ERROR] [1664263597.180336063] [UR_Client_Library]: Failed to connect to robot on IP 192.168.1.102. Please check that the robot is booted and reachable on 192.168.1.102. Retrying in 10 seconds
```

Afterwards I start the URCap file on the Panel. There i get the following error

```
The connection to the remote PC at 192.168.1.110:50002 could not be established. Reason: connection time out
```

or

```
The connection to the remote PC at 192.168.1.110:50002 could not be established. Reason: No route to host (Host unreachable)
```

or

```
The connection to the remote PC at 192.168.1.110:50002 could not be established. Reason: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

My ROS2 is running in VMware on Ubuntu 20.04.  In my VM, I set up a additional network adapter. The already existing one is set to NAT. The new one is set to network bridge, where i chose the `Realtek PCIe Gbe Family Controller` which should be my Ethernet socket, where my LAN cable from the UR is connected to. The second Adapter has a static IP address: 192.168.1.110.

Pinging the UR from the virtual machine is possible:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.56 ms
```

A Ping is possible if both network adapters are activated or just any of them.

Does any of you have a idea where the problem is and how to solve this?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407009/connecting-to-universal-robot/) by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here the UR-Forum with the solution.

https://forum.universal-robots.com/t/connect-to-ur-with-ros2/24085

---

Originally posted by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) with karma: 42 on 2022-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-05**:
Could you please quote the relevant parts from that discussion so your answer here is stand-alone?

UR has made their fora only accessible to people with an account in the past (and then changed it back), which if it would happen again would make your link inaccessible. By copy-pasting the relevant parts here, we avoid that problem.

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-05**:
Here we go

```
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [FATAL] [1664881747.865636229] [URPositionHardwareInterface]: Variable 'speed_slider_mask' is currently controlled by another RTDE client. The input recipe can't be used as configured
```

There seems to be something else running on the robot using the RTDE input fields. Do you have a fieldbus activated? We had a section for that in the [ROS1 driver’s README](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#when-starting-the-driver-it-crashes-with-variable-speed_slider_mask-is-currently-controlled-by-another-rtde-client) that seems not to have made it to the ROS2 driver.

This could also be caused by another URCap installed on the robot.

Let me add that we are currently working on replacing the requirement on RTDE inputs for most things, but we won’t be able to ditch the RTDE inputs completely in the near future.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-05**:
So what was the specific cause in your case?

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-05**:
I hast to disable the EtherNet/IP like explained in the ROS1 driver‘s README.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-05**:
You mean EtherNet/IP, correct?

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-05**:
ah, yes. changed that.